# How to override javascript function "_title_changed" in webclient odoo

Tags: javascript, web, overriding, odoo-14, page-title

My goal is to change the Page title using the company name. I am trying to change the function but still there's no effect. Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
var session = require('web.session');
var AbstractWebClient = require('web.AbstractWebClient');

AbstractWebClient.include({
    _title_changed: function () {
        this._super();
        var company_name = session.user_companies.current_company[1];
        document.title = company_name;
        console.log('_title_changed function');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am lacking was odoo.define().

This is what I did:

```
odoo.define('my_module.AbstractWebClient', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    
/**
 * AbstractWebClient Override Method for Page Title
 */

var session = require('web.session');
var AbstractWebClient = require('web.AbstractWebClient');

AbstractWebClient.include({
    _title_changed: function () {
        this._super();
        var company_name = session.user_companies.current_company[1];
        document.title = company_name;
        console.log('_title_changed function');
    },
});

return AbstractWebClient;

});
```